# Intent doesn't start after Thread sleep

Tags: android, android-intent

I know this is a common problem but couldn't find the solution. I am trying to make an intent that starts after 5 seconds. So when application starts, one screen-5sec sleep-other screen. There is no error, just other class doesn't show up.

First class that application starts, name is Acilis.class

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.acilis);
    Thread sayac = new Thread(){
        public void baslat(){
            try {
                sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                Intent intent_basla = new Intent("android.example.CINSIYET");
                startActivity(intent_basla);
            }
        }
    };
    sayac.start();
}
```

I also tried

```
Intent intent_basla = new Intent(Acilis.this, Cinsiyet.class");
```

And xml file

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.Acilis"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.Cinsiyet"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.example.CINSIYET"></action>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final Handler handle = new Handler();
        Runnable delay = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

            Intent intent= new Intent(Main.this,bla.class); 
                             startActivity(intent);
            }
        };
        handle.postDelayed(delay,5000);
```